# How to add a BOM to an HTML document

Tags: html, unicode, utf-16, byte-order-mark

From the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/document-metadata.html#character-encoding-declaration):

> If an HTML document does not start with a BOM, and its encoding is not explicitly given by Content-Type metadata, and the document is not an iframe srcdoc document, then the character encoding used must be an ASCII-compatible character encoding

So How I can add a BOM which would mean the document is encoded in UTF16 for example?

Comment: Do any browsers even reliably support those encodings?

Comment: How are you encoding the document in those encodings in the first place? You should configure whatever tool you are using to set the encoding to include the BOM at the same time.

Comment: @Pekka Unicode are standards for many years now. DO you know well-know program which don't support UTF32? :)

Comment: @user do you see a UTF-32 encoding in Chrome's or Firefox's encoding menus?

Comment: @Quentin : like many peoples I use a text/advanced text editor for editing HTML files. Usually you choose to set the character encoding when you record the file. It re-open with right encoding in the editor, but you've got very strange result if you do the same in a web-browser (tried webkit/blink/presto/trident) :) . Since utf-8 is ascii compatible you just need to specify the right <meta> element. But According to the W3C, you need to add a BOM at the beginning of the HTML document to let character encoding like UTF-16 or UTF-323 work properly.

Comment: @Pekka: For firefox and chrome, I don't know... but seen in midori, thunderbird and Opera

Comment: It's not there in FF and Chrome. UTF-8 is generally the way to go on the Web at the moment.

Comment: @Pekka웃 : Yes, with the exception of some charsets.... Thunderbird use gecko midori webkit and Opera blink... I'm seeing no reason why it shouldn't be in chrome and FF.

Comment: UTF8 can handle all character sets.  That said, you haven't told us your operating system or editor.  It will be an editor option to provide the BOM.  For example, on Windows, Notepad++ can set the encoding to `UTF8 with BOM` or `UTF16` (which provides the BOM).

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Read the comments... I don't really care about the editor for the conversion. In reality, I used the `iconv` command.

Comment: @Pekka웃 : [Firefox support UTF-32](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=604317 "Mozilla official bugzilla")

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/381056/iconv-generating-utf-16-with-bom

Comment: @MarkTolonen Ah Ok.... I thought the byte oder mask referred to the html language like the <meta> element do. I didn't know it was about the files in general... I don't have necessary rights for migrating this question, since in that case, it is not programming related.

Comment: note: the main advantage of UTF-32 is that it is a fixed length encoding.

Comment: Now it's off topic, I would prefer this question migrated rather than closed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The byte order mask is an hex sequence which can be put at the beginning of any file.
It has nothing to do with the html/other web languages.

An hex editor is a good way to add it.

Although UTF-32 offer the advantage of fixed length encoding, some browser/e-mail client dropped the support for it.

note: UTF-16 is mainly used on windows.

Answer (score 2):

You add a BOM by inserting U+FEFF (which is what the BOM is by definition) at the very start of the data. How you do that depends on how you are generating UTF-16 or UTF-32 in the first place.

The “rephrased” question “how I can display an utf-16/utf-32 encoded html document?” is really a different, and the short answer is: mostly, you don’t. There is hardly any reason to use utf-16 or utf-32 for an HTML document. The recommendations clearly favor utf-8. But if you use utf-16 or utf-32, then you should primarily take care of `Content-Type` header, and *additionally* include a BOM.

Comment: Again the content type header is for http only, not in e-mails... I recognize there are some problems according to the official [Unicode website](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-5) which make some peoples prefer non standard encodings...

Comment: @user UTF-8 is very much a standard encoding. As far as the web is concerned, it currently is the lowest common denominator and the ideal way to go.

Comment: @user2284570, proper e-mail format (MIME) has Content-Type headers.

Answer (score 1):

The hint is here:

> its encoding is not **explicitly given by Content-Type metadata**

You should try that (by HTTP headers or by  etc.) For inserting the BOM, your code editor should be able to do that.

Please also see the W3C specs:

> Most of the time you are probably better off choosing UTF-8 as your
>   encoding. [...] One reason for this is that there are special rules
>   for declaring the encoding of a UTF-16 page.
>
> Whether you use element-based declarations or not, you should ensure
>   that you always have a byte-order mark at the very start of a UTF-16
>   encoded file. In effect, this is the in-document declaration.
>
> Furthermore, if your page is encoded as UTF-16, do not declare your
>   file to be "UTF-16BE" or "UTF-16LE", use "UTF-16" only. The byte-order
>   mark at the beginning of your file will indicate whether the encoding
>   scheme is little-endian or big-endian. (This is because content
>   explicitly encoded as, say, UTF-16BE should not use a byte-order mark;
>   but HTML5 requires a byte-order mark for UTF-16 encoded pages.)

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations#utf16

Comment: the http header is well-know to for dealing with this... unfortunately it won't work in e-mails. I need a general-purpose solution.`For inserting the BOM, your code editor should be able to do that.` : not found in vi geany windows wordpad.exe and notepad.exe. I guess I have to do it manually but I don't know how. That's the purpose of this question.

Comment: @user2284570: For vi(m), please see this one: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode, especially "'bomb' (boolean): if set, vim will put a "byte order mark" (or BOM for short) at the start of Unicode files."

Comment: @user2284570: Geany: http://www.geany.org/manual/#character-sets-and-unicode-byte-order-mark-bom
On Windows, use Notepad++ instead; it can handle BOM well.

Comment: In plain old notepad.exe, use Unicode as the save option for what is really UTF16.  It will have a BOM. There is a UTF8 option as well.  It will also have a BOM.

Comment: @MarkTolonen : I doubt of that... currently the page is correctly displayed... but as text file not html. This is due to the encoding...

Comment: Use a hex editor and look at the beginning of the file.  `FF FE` is a little-endian UTF-16 BOM.